# Showing a function is Lipschitz continuous

Tags: inequality, continuity, lipschitz-functions

I am trying to prove the following:

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $B_r$ the closed ball in $X$ centered at $0$ and of radius $r$.

Then the map $f:X\to B_r$ defined by
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \left.
\begin{cases}
      x, & |x|\leq r\\
      r\frac{x}{|x|}, &  |x|\geq r
        \end{cases}
\right.
\end{equation}
is Lipschitz-continuous with constant $2$.

**My work:**

If $x,y\in B_r$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|=|x-y|\leq 2|x-y|$.

If $|x|,|y|\geq r$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|=r|\frac{x}{|x|}-\frac{y}{|y|}|=\frac{r}{|x|}|x-\frac{|x|}{|y|}y|\leq (|x-y|+|y-\frac{|x|}{|y|}y|)\leq 2|x-y|$.

Now, I'm having difficulties to prove the remaining case:

$|f(x)-f(y)|=|x-r\frac{y}{|y|}|\leq 2|x-y|$, for $x\leq r$ and $y\geq r$.

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're almost done. Just note that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |f(x)-f(r)|+|f(y)-f(r)|$, which has already been proved to be no more than $2(r-x)+2(y-r)=2(y-x)$.

Comment: @ Cave Johnson Thanks.